# Accessing Properties from Subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having problems working out how to access properties of an rxJS Subscription in an angular 2 project.

I know my service is working as i can put {{selectedCustomer.name}} in my template and it shows me the name, i just cannot figure out how to access this in my componnent so i can assign it as part of the ngInit.

If someone can assist on how to do this, would be greatly appreciated

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Customer } from "./customer-model";

import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";

declare var firebase: any;

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

    // customer: Customer;
    customer: FirebaseObjectObservable<Customer[]>;
    customers: FirebaseListObservable<Customer[]>;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

    getCustomers(category: string = null) {
        if (category != null) {
            this.customers = this.af.database.list('customer', {
                query: {
                    orderByChild: 'category',
                    equalTo: category
                }
            });

        } else {

            this.customers = this.af.database.list('customer') as FirebaseListObservable<Customer[]>;

        }

        return this.customers;
    }

    getCustomer(customerIndex: number) {

        this.af.database.object('/customer/' + customerIndex)
            .subscribe(customer => {
                this.customer = customer;
            });
        return this.customer;
    }

    addCustomer(customer: Customer) {

        // Get new unique key for customer
        var customerKey = firebase.database().ref().child('customer').push().key;

        // Create reference to new customer key
        var newCustomer = {};
        newCustomer['/customer/' + customerKey] = customer;

        return firebase.database().ref().update(newCustomer);
    }

    deleteCustomer(customerIndex: number) {
         this.af.database.object('/customer/' + customerIndex).remove();
    }

}
```

**Template**

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddCustomer()">
  <md-card class="demo-card demo-basic">
    <md-toolbar color="primary">Edit</md-toolbar>
    <md-card-content>
      <br>
      <table style="width: 100%" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <md-input placeholder="Organisation" style="width: 100%" formControlName="name" type="test" id="name" #name></md-input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <md-input placeholder="Description" style="width: 100%" formControlName="description" type="test" id="description" #description></md-input>
          </td>
          <td>
            <md-input placeholder="Image Url" style="width: 100%" formControlName="imagePath" type="test" id="imagePath" #imagePath></md-input>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>

</form>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

import { Customer } from '../customer-model';
import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'mj-customer-edit',
  templateUrl: './customer-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-edit.component.css']
})
export class CustomerEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  error = false;
  errorMessage = '';

  private subscription: Subscription;
  private customerIndex: number;
  selectedCustomer: FirebaseObjectObservable<Customer[]>;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      this.customerIndex = params['key'];
      this.selectedCustomer = this.customerService.getCustomer(this.customerIndex);
    })
    **This is where I want to assign the values on my form to the customer object that i get back from the service**

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      imagePath: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to     subscribe to your customer service too.

```
this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
          this.customerIndex = params['key'];
          this.customerService.getCustomer(this.customerIndex).subscribe((res) => {
              this.selectedCustomer = res;
              //extra assignments with selectedCustomer object here.
          });
        })
```

Edit: Added service code

```
getCustomer(customerIndex: number) {

    return this.af.database.object('/customer/' + customerIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - if i try that i get a compile error saying Type 'Customer[]' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<Customer[]>'.

Comment: Yes sorry that would help.  I have updated the question with the service code.

Comment: @ccocker I added service code too. You subscribe twice but was not waiting for async call. You would get default object all the time. Just return your call and subscribe to it.

Comment: Great Thank you so much